# Uploading a django project to a github repo

Tags: django, git

I am relatively new to github and I am still trying to take my django application into production using a github repository. The problem is that for some reason, github has refused to commit a certain folder to the main branch. When I try to commit the changes I get the following message:

```
On branch main
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        blog/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

So I assume its telling me that there are some untracked files within the blog folder but when I try to add the folder, I get the following error:

```
warning: adding embedded git repository: blog
hint: You've added another git repository inside your current repository.
hint: Clones of the outer repository will not contain the contents of    
hint: the embedded repository and will not know how to obtain it.        
hint: If you meant to add a submodule, use:
hint: 
hint:   git submodule add <url> blog
hint: 
hint: If you added this path by mistake, you can remove it from the
hint: index with:
hint: 
hint:   git rm --cached blog
hint: 
hint: See "git help submodule" for more information.
```

It appears, its treating it as a github repository, even though it is a folder within my project. So here is my file system:

```
blog---(main project folder with the settings.py, this is the folder that is refusing to commit)
|
media
|
posts
|
static
|
templates
|
manage.py
|
some other system files
```

What could be the issue? is it that I might have previously uploaded a repo with the same name and linked it to the same project file, but later deleted it. I am at a loss. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> warning: adding embedded git repository: blog
> ```
>
> It appears, its treating it as a github repository ...

It is indeed a *Git* repository.  (Git*Hub* is a commercial web site that, among other things they do, includes the hosting of Git repositories.)

> even though it is a folder within my project

The `blog` folder is the *working tree* for this other Git repository.

A Git repository cannot actually contain another Git repository.  Git's "hint" messages here are poor quality, but are correct: your "outer" repository is going to *list the other repository as something that someone should clone*, rather than actually contain the "inner" repository.  But to list this *correctly* requires that you use `git submodule add`.  If you allow things to proceed as they are, you'll get a *broken* submodule, or what I like to call a "half-assed" submodule.  Git calls what it's going to store a *gitlink* and this is only half of a real submodule: the other half are instructions that Git needs later to *clone the other Git repository*.

If you wish to use submodules—and this is often a bad idea: people call them *sob*-modules with good reason—use `git submodule add`.  If you *don't* wish to use submodules, make sure you aren't adding the working tree of a Git repository.

To make the `blog` folder *not* be the working tree of a Git repository, move the entire Git repository—including the working tree—somewhere else, make a *new* `blog` folder, and copy into that `blog` folder the files and sub-folders you'd like to put into your regular Git repository.  (Note that `blog` currently contains a hidden folder named `.git`, which in turn contains the main repository databases and other ancillary control files for this second Git repository.)

To make the `blog` folder a proper submodule, use `git rm --cached blog`, as the hint says, then use `git submodule add`, as the hint says.  Read up on sobmodules, er, I mean, submodules first.

Comment: question is, how do I move the blog folder and the working tree somewhere else? Is there a specific command?

Comment: And basically what I think the easier way is, how can I permanently delete this folder as a git repo? because I never meant it for it to be a git repo in the first place. This is like an app within an app

Comment: On a Linux system, just `mv blog ../orignal-blog` for instance. You're probably on Windows, so I don't know if you can rename-move a directory like this. (On the rare occasions when I have been forced to use Windows, I used a Unix-like interface that provided an `mv` command that just worked.)

Comment: To (perhaps irrevocably) destroy the "Git-ness" of some folder, enter the folder and then recursively remove the hidden `.git` folder, with whatever tool your OS provides. On Linux this is just `rm -rf .git`. Note that it cannot be undone, which is why the more general description I provided above says "move it out of the way, then copy what you want". That way the original is safe if you decide you do want it after all.

Comment: What you mean is a terminal emulator, and yes I have one on my pc. Its called gitbash. There are several others in the market, like zsh that perform the same function. The move command worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Git-bash is not a terminal emulator: it's a port of bash (a freeware shell for Unix/Linux systems) to Windows. It's just supplied *with* Git-for-Windows, because Git needs a Unix-style shell. It runs in a terminal emulator but git-bash itself doesn't provide the terminal emulator; that's already there, on Windows. But, yes, if you have bash-for-Windows it should have those other utilities with it.

Comment: I'll add here that some people use a different version of Git on Windows that apparently doesn't come with bash (though I'm not sure how they manage the required shell part). Things may have changed some since the early 2010s though (last time I had to do this sort of thing was almost a decade ago).